# NBA Fixture Ticker - Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image: NBA Fixture Ticker (Draft)]

I'm trying to create a fixture ticker for the NBA season using Elo ratings. I've put together a rudimentary example of what I'm trying to achieve (Elo ratings aren't accurate). I have a dropdown list in "B3" containing every player in the league. In cell "E3", I'm using a vlookup formula in conditional formatting, to view "C3", look it up in array "C11:G15", using "E8" as the column reference to return the Elo number. What I'm having trouble with, is once the Elo rating has been found (in this case 1624), how to check whether the number is between the ranges specified in the key, so that a correct color can be assigned. I understand I'll need to multiply the rule based on each step of the key, such that when I decide to change to player in cell "B3" from the dropdown list, the cell color will change accordingly, with the Elo rating number retrieved.

I've tried using Vlookup combined with IF & AND statements to no avail

Comment: So you're looking up a number to a text string. It's better to list the start values (numbers, not text) only in column I.

Answer (score 0):

If you combine `XMATCH` with an array of the desired lower bounds, it will return a number that you can use to set the rules. For this application, you would need to create 7 conditional formatting rules with the format

```
=XMATCH(E13,{1300,1351,1401,1451,1500,1550,1600}, -1) = n
```

Where n is an integer from 1 to 7.

Comment: The key is for illustrative purposes. In cell E3, in conditional formatting, using the rule "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". I have: =VLOOKUP($C3,$C$11:$G$15,E$8,FALSE). This looks up the team name in the array, using E8 as the column reference. If for example I change Dončić to Wembanyama from the dropdown, C3 will change to San Antonio Spurs, the opponent cell will swap and vlookup will find the value 1401. What I'm having trouble with is, once vlookup has found the value, determining whether it is between the number's specified in the key, so it can be colored accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Works perfectly, Thankyou so much